# PHP force a var to have a certain type

Tags: mysql, variables, string

This may be a stupid question but I might aswell as it :)

is there away to force

```
$tel1 = '05';// string
settype($tel1,'string');
$tel1 = 06;//either throw error, or convert it to string automatically.
var_dump($tel1);//(string [2]) 05
```

The above code is of the top of my head so might not be accurate but I need to keep a variable as a string not numeric, because of some silly thing I have done, now my phone numbers lose the leading 0s :-(

n I cn't rewrite it because it will mess up with other numeric types,b4 u ask it was an automated service for db to check if it was a numeric value or not,

UPDATE
This is the problem

```
function escape($str){
   if(is_numeric($str)){
       return $str;
   }else{
       return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($str).'\'';
   }
}
$tel1 = "06";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id = '.escape($tel1).'';
//above is same as below
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id = 06 ';
```

I can't change anything inside the scape function because other inputes thruout the website are using this function, I dont wanna mess their validations.

Comment: Typecasting/type juggling. `(int)$tel1` or `(string)$tel1`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `is_numeric` tests for numeric content, not an integer type. But then you take a variable called `$str` which implies you *want* it to be a string.

Perhaps use:

```
function escape($val) {
   if (is_numeric($val) && !is_string($val)) {
       return $val;
   }
   else{
       return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . '\'';
   }
}
```

Now strings will be escaped and quoted, but *not* if they contain only numeric content.

Comment: thats the problem because this was written monkeys [ages] ago and thats the problem I don't know if I change `escape` it may effect other inputs if that makes sense, and they are on different pages ,

Comment: but this is something I might consider :)

Comment: @Val: Well other than this I don't really understand the question, then.

Comment: oh no you are right, the code is written along time ago, but i cnt change escape function, just incase other validations fail on other pages of the website. but I will check other inputs if they are effected or not,

Comment: @Val: "affected". They shouldn't be; the escape function will still be just as "safe" as before.

Comment: I will go with this one, but i'm still 0.00000001% unsure if somin silly will not work later lol, but O well will have to cross that bridge when I need to lool thnx

Comment: @Val: Your question is, as far as I can tell, about changing the way `escape` works, to continue escaping and quoting strings even if they're numeric. So, no matter how that's accomplished, you need to change `escape`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
$string = (string) $int;
```

or use a function

```
$string = strval($int);
```

Comment: its slightly complicated, I know about (string) 06, please look at line 3 again, I want `$tel1` to be `$tel = "06";//string ` not 06 as integer,

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a variable to a specific type in the global scope.

You can force `Array`s and `Object`s in a function.

```
function getElementsByClassName(DOMNode $parentElement, Array $classNames) {
 ... 
}
```

If you pass an object that is not an instantiation of `DOMNode` (or a subclass), or if you don't pass an `Array` as the second argument, you'll get an error.

You can of course cast any variable, e.g. `(string) $tel1`.

You shouldn't be treating phone numbers as `Int`s anyway, because of leading zeroes and possible parenthesis and dashes. Also, once your telephone number is an `Int`, it won't know its `0` padding anymore because it will be discarded, so casting it back won't give you the original `String`.

Comment: Thats what I need to do to keep a tel number as a string, but its automatically converted to integer when inserted on db because of the escape function [see updated on answer]

Comment: @Val Can you [change it to `is_int()`](http://codepad.org/RrMdtniu). Alternatively, remove the condition and just pass everything through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, quote delimited.

Answer (score 0):

To cast a variable you can use something like:

```
$i = 1;
$s = (string) $i;
```

Depending on the db adaptor you might not be able to detect the type being returned from the database. I believe it's PDO that returns everything (even INT values) as strings.

The `number_format()` function may be of use to you too.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable as:

```
$var = 06;
```

it immediately becomes 6 without leading zero because leading zero when it comes to integers is meaningless and therefore it's cut out.

In other words, your variable has to be created as string, which is what you probably deduced yourself.

Quick fix would be the following: you can add another parameter to your escape() function.

For example:

```
function escape($str, $force_str = false)
{
    if($force_str) 
    { 
        // do your conversion, the rest of the site will by default pass false so nothing will be broken 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As alex said, start by making sure the phone number is never converted from string to int in your own code. Then, you need to make sure it will not be converted when sent to your SQL DB.
It ought to work if you do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($tel1) . "'";
```

This is the same as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id = '06'";
```